# Turtlebot Linear Y has no response

Tags: ros, turtlebot, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to do Turtlebot Simulation.
I am giving Linear x & Linear y .
But it seems like linear Y has no effect.

Then i tried below simple code to check linear y effect.
after code run there is no movement in Y direction.
Please tell reason-

==========================================================================

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

def Move():
        Pub = rospy.Publisher('mobile_base/commands/velocity' , Twist , queue_size=20)

        command = Twist()
        command.linear.x = 0
        command.linear.y = 1
        command.linear.z = 0
        command.angular.x = 0
        command.angular.y = 0
        command.angular.z = 0

        r = rospy.Rate(100)

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                Pub.publish(command)

                r.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
        rospy.init_node('TurtleControl')
        Move()
```

==========================================================================

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199866/turtlebot-linear-y-has-no-response/) by [Apoorv](https://answers.ros.org/users/21182/apoorv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That `geometry_msgs/Twist` message is expressed in a frame attached to the base of the robot with it's x-axis in the forward direction, the y-axis to the side, and the z-axis up. See [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html). The  turtlebot has a "non-holonomic constraint" which means in its mathematical model (and really the actual robot) it cannot slide sideways (in the y-direction). This model is often called a unicycle model or a kinematic car model. The result is that the commands the turtlebot accepts are a forward translational velocity (twist.linear.x), and an angular velocity (twist.angular.z).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Apoorv](https://answers.ros.org/users/21182/apoorv/) on 2014-12-20**:
thanks.
So if i have to move turtlebot in Y direction as well , how to calculate twist.angular.z.
I have calculated X direction & Y direction velocities.

I do not know how to convert Y direction velocity into corresponding twist.angular.z
Please help.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-20**:
You cannot ever have a Y direction velocity in the frame attached to the robot. If you want it to move in both the y and x direction w.r.t. a world frame, you'd first have to rotate the robot and then translate in the direction that you'd want to go. Or use a controller to follow the desired dir.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-20**:
IMO, the paper *Control of Wheeled Mobile Robots: An Experimental Overview* provides a nice introduction to the model the turtlebot uses and several different strategies for controlling it. [http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~labrob/pub/papers/Ramsete01.pdf](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/%7Elabrob/pub/papers/Ramsete01.pdf)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-20**:
If you're going to use ROS navigation eventually, you could also check out some of the local planners such as `dwa_local_planner` or `eband_local_planner`. These planners control the robot to follow a path while avoiding obstacles.